# MVC Installation taking ~Forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I went to [this page](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/) and clicked on the "Install the ASP.NET MVC Framework using the Web Platform Installer" link and proceeded with the installation.

The only option I selected was to install the Web Deployment Tool and now I am staring at the following screen for the last 2 hours with no updates to the progress bar
[screen image](http://screencast.com/t/N2Y3ZGNkMDQt)

I assume that I am installing the MVC framework (that was the intent) as well as an optional Web Platform Installer component but I am concerned about the lack of progress of the installation and the length of time that it is taking.

I am afraid of aborting the installation and leaving my PC in an ugly state. Sometimes the uninstall cancellation takes longer that the installation would have.

Does this installation normally takes this long?

Comment: What did you end up doing? Cancelling it? or did you force kill the installer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Normally just a few minutes depending on net speed.

Comment: I would just download it instead of using the Web Installer, too. Hope it works out.

Answer (score 0):

Well Don't forget about the standalone MVC 4 installer as well.
It needs only 35.93 MB.
Can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683)! .

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, always stick with the "Offline" installer if possible. I have been working in IT for a very long time and have lost track on the amount of failed installations due to the "online" installer. I have spent countless hours rebuilding systems due to it so stick with offline and you should be good.